# Android widget textview with sharedpreferences

Tags: android, widget, textview, sharedpreferences

I make a widget that contains 4 textview for my app

Those 4 textview should receive the text from sharepreferences

The widget work fine but the problem with getting the data

This is the widget class code

```
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.preference.*;
import android.gesture.*;

public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider{
 TextView b95,b98,mred,mgreen;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    LoadPreferences();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action))
    {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                                            R.layout.widget);

        AppWidgetManager
            .getInstance(context)
            .updateAppWidget(
            intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS),
            views);
    }

}
private void LoadPreferences()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String p95 = sharedPreferences.getString("p2p95", "");
    String p98 = sharedPreferences.getString("p2p98", "");
    String pred = sharedPreferences.getString("p2pred", "");
    String pgreen = sharedPreferences.getString("p2pgreen", "");

    b95.setText(p95);
    b98.setText(p98);
    mred.setText(pred);
    mgreen.setText(pgreen);

}
}
```

First of all I have a problem with (this) in the loadpreferences method they say I cannot use it

Second I guess all the load preferences is wrong to use it with widget

So what is the solution

Any help??

Answer (score 0):

```
String Harneet="hi";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putString("Name",Harneet);
  editor.commit();
```

After you want the value use below code

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String p95 = sharedPreferences.getString("p2p95", "Harneet");
```